# How to render a special character using HTML in Shiny R?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to display a greek letter delta as a symbol.
The unicode and encoding can be found [here](https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+0394).

```
output$text <- renderText({
      HTML("Displaying greek letter delta as a symbol: \u0394")
    })
```

This results in exactly the same string when rendered instead of a symbol. Same happens when using "&#916;" or "&#x394;". Maybe someone knows how to correctly format text with special symbols when using `HTML()` in R, or share any documentation relating this?

The desired output is: "Displaying greek letter delta as a symbol: Δ"

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    HTML("Displaying greek letter delta as a symbol: \u0394")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use **renderUI** and **uiOutput** instead of **renderText** and **textOutput**.

Comment: When I run your code I get the expected delta symbol *i.e.* "Displaying greek letter delta as a symbol: Δ". I got this using &#916; or u0394. Maybe the R/Shiny version is causing the problem. Mines are R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt) and shiny_1.7.1

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thank you, this has solved my issue. Do you know why using renderUI/uiOutput works instead of renderText/textOutput? Is it a good practice to use renderUI/uiOutput in general or just in this case?

Comment: **uiOutput** is a synonym of **htmlOutput**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important:** if you need to use HTML elements such as `<br>`, you will need to follow @Stéphane Laurent's comment and use `renderUi()` and `uiOutput()`.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderUI({
    HTML("<p> Displaying greek letter delta as a symbol:<br> \u0394 
         </p>")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

With:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
shiny_1.7.1
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
```

Comment: I am running R version 4.1.2 & the same shiny version.  So could be potentially, the R version issue.

Comment: **HTML** is not needed here.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I turned the answer to community wiki as your comments helped me a lot to understand what was going on. Feels free to post your answer as an actual one.